# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException when using grails dynamic finder

Tags: grails, save, finder

Using Grails i'm trying a dynamic finder like this one

```
Policy.findAllByResourceAndUser(resource,user)
```

But When i call this, grails raise this exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: object references
an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: gmedia.User;
nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved
transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: gmedia.User
```

Do we need to save the parameter of the finder?
Where i'm wrong?

Comment: need to see additional code, specifically where "resource" & "user" values are coming from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.grails.org/DomainClass+Dynamic+Methods#findAllBy*

Policy.findAllByResourceAndUser(resource,user)

capital "B" in "By"  is the first thing I see wrong? Is that a type on the question?

```
 def res = new Resource(name:"resource name").save()
 def user = new User(name:"My Name").save()
 def policy = new Policy( user:user, resource:res, right: "right string").save()

 println Policy.findAllByResourceAndUser(res,user)
```

not elegant, but you get the idea, there must be a problem in the way you are saving your objects

your user object will "never" get saved with that code... you have to specify values for all of you properties or define your constraints appropriately. I think you should review the documentation for Domain Objects in Grails because it appears there are fundamental problems in your approach see http://www.grails.org/GORM+-+Creating+a+domain+class

Comment: sorry, just a typing error. The actual code was correctly typed. i'll edit the question text.

Comment: looks like ou have not saved/flushed the user object.. I wrote a test case and the code runs fine

Comment: In fact i try to do a findAll... at a point where i should find no Policy (for testing purpose)

Comment: @BenZen dont really understand your comment

Comment: i did a test case too. The test that raise this exception, the resource is saved, the user is saved, but the policy doesn't exist. Plus there is no ressource. Is that a probleme?

Comment: i tryed to modify my finder like this "Policy.findAllByResource", and it work, except that it is the the beheaviour i want

Comment: @BenZen what are you saying? There is no resource?? there has to be a resource unless you say nullable is true. I would suggest you post the code from you test case because whatever it is you are saying is not coming thru very well

Comment: I wont give my complete test case cause it's a bit complicated, but it end to be like this                                                   def res = new Resource(name:"resource name").save()
 def user = new User(name:"My Name").save()
 println Policy.findAllByResourceAndUser(res,user)

Comment: your user object will "never" get saved with that code... you have to specify values for all of you properties or define your constraints appropriately. I think you should review the documentation for Domain Objects in Grails because it appears there are fundamental problems in your approach  http://www.grails.org/GORM+-+Creating+a+domain+class

Comment: ohh, you're totally right, can you put this on the answer. This way i ll be able to make my question as answered. Bonus question, why grom doesn't show a message to warn that i was trying to save an "uncomplite" entity?

Answer (score 0):

@Aaron Saunders
these are two domain class

```
class Resource{
static contraints={}
}

class User extends Resource{
  String name
  String password
  String email
  Date creationDate
  Date lastModicationDate
}

class Policy{
Resource resource
User user
String right
static mapping={
  user cascade:'all-delete-orpahn'
  resource cascade:'all-delete-orpahn'
}
```

Maybe it a consequence of the inheritance between User and Resource

Comment: where is the Policy Domain Object?

Comment: Completely unrelated, but your constraints block has to be static like the mapping block, otherwise it'll be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue today..i found the solution...there is a foreign key relation which is getting set as NULL.....so when it tries to save null it throws this exception..so make sure all the values are not null...else u may need to change the cascade definition in ur mapping xml..

Comment: The error message already indicates this isn't a foreign key constraint problem, but one involving transient fields - the DAO code would give a different error in such a case.